# Can't Change CSS of Span Through jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

In my below coe the `console.log` fires, so the `if` statement is definitely passing. If I try to `console.log()` the CSS of `$(this)` I get `undefined`. I've done `console.log($this)` and it returns an object with outer HTML `<span class="formState"></span>`. I've had a few friends look at this and have done a lot of research but have come up short.

```
<span class="formState"><?php echo $IRFormResults[$count];$count++ ?></span>
```

```js
$(".formState").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == 'n/a') {
        console.log('Got an n/a');
        $(this).css('color:red');
    }
```

```css
.formState {
    color: green;
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 125px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right. The `css()` method takes two parameters; the CSS property and its value:

```
$(this).css('color', 'red');
```

Also note that you can amend your logic to use a `filter()` and also to `trim()` the text of the element to save any whitespace causing problems:

```
$(".formState").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().toLower().trim() == 'n/a';
}).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Alright, you're totally right. Thanks so much. Though, how would I approach printing out its existing css? Just incase I wanted to.

Comment: It's actually quite complicated to get all the CSS rules on an element because there are hundreds of default settings applied by the browser before you put any styling on it yourself. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should change this:

```
$(this).css('color:red');
```

To this :

```
$(this).css('color','red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

`$(this).css('color','red');`

or

`$(this).css({'color':'red'});`